# Blending in Different OpenGL editions

Tags: opengl, blend

Below is a piece of code I use to achieve a demo about how blending works:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3i(2, 0, 0);
    glVertex3i(2, 6, 0);
    glVertex3i(6, 6, 0);
    glVertex3i(6, 0, 0);
glEnd();

glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5f);
    glVertex3i(3, 2, -1);
    glVertex3i(3, 8, -1);
    glVertex3i(8, 8, -1);
    glVertex3i(8, 2, -1);
glEnd();
```

The problem is: It shows what I want on my laptop, which means that the intersection of the two quads is blended, and the area of the green quad left out on black background also blended with background whose alpha is 0.0. However, on another PC, only the red quad appears...

The OpenGL on the laptop is 2.0, and the one on the PC is over 4.0. I want to know whether the problem is the edition of OpenGL or not.

BTW: I know the order I should follow when I want to draw a translucent and an opaque object; I only use this demo to show how much trouble there will be if we do not follow it...

Comment: No, it's very unlikely that the version of OpenGL is the problem.  Rahter, you're trying to use use destination alpha values (e.g., `GL_DST_ALPHA`) which require your window to have been created with those bitplanes, otherwise I think alpha's mapped to one.  Verify that your window really does have destination alpha planes (call `glGetIntegerv( GL_ALPHA_BITS, &bits );`).  If `bits == 0` your window doesn't have destination alpha planes.

Comment: Oh yes, I check the alpha bitplane and fine out that it's 8 on my laptop and 0 on my PC. But I don't quite understand your explanation: I'm using GLUT to create the window with the GLUT_RGBA paramter to init it, and I'm sure that I clear the background with (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) which should pass a zero-alpha value. As I thought, how can the window doesn't have alpha bitplanes?